# Kendo Editor Dynamic Link onClick Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I have a custom toolbar which inserts a link in kendo editor. I am trying to put a onClick function in that link but when the dynamically inserted link is clicked it says function is not defined. I also tried it by putting a class on that link and have a click function to that class but it does not get hit.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$("toolbarSubmitBtn").("click", function () {
    var value = $("toolbarInput").val();

    var $html = '<a onClick="myFunction()"> Click to show alert </a>';
    //var $html = '<a class="functioncall"> Click to show alert </a>';
    var $empty = $("<div>").append($html)
    $("#editor").data("kendoEditor").paste($empty.html());
});
```

Class Call

```
$(document).on("click", ".functioncall", function () {
    alert("function called from class");
});
```

Function Call

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("function called by click");
}
```

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the Kendo Editor puts the body content within an IFRAME and your "myFunction" is not within that IFRAME.  Try setting the onClick to

```
window.parent.myFunction();


$("#toolbarSubmitBtn").on("click", function () {
    var $html = '<a href="#" onClick="window.parent.myFunction();" contenteditable="false"> Click to show alert </a>';          
    $("#editor").data("kendoEditor").paste($html);
});
```

Optionally, set `contenteditable="false"` on your inserted link to prevent user editing the link text.

Here is a [DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/ORUwUwIb)